# implementation of excel function 'filter' in vba

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have filter function in excel and it works well in excel spreadsheet. I wrote this function in cell G7. Following is the function. [Click here for reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pjaxq.jpg)

```
=FILTER(A3:C19,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("nut",B3:B19)),"Not found")
```

I need to implement this in VBA. So I wrote following code in vba:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G7").Value = Filter(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:C19"), WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(WorksheetFunction.Search("nut", Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3:B19"))), "Not found")
```

However this gives me error "Run time error 13: type mismatch". What is my mistake? An expert advice is needed.

Thanks..

Comment: VBA `Filter` function and the Excel `FILTER` function are two completely different functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `Application.Filter` not `Filter`, `Filter` is a VBA function, and you should return the result to a variant variable.

```vb
Dim Res As Variant

    With Application
        Res = .Filter(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:C19"), .IsNumber(.Search("nut", Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3:B19"))), "Not found")
    End With
    
    If Not IsError(Res) Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G7").Resize(UBound(Res, 1), 3).Value = Res
    End If
```

Comment: Many thanks.. It worked as expected

Comment: It works but when I enter "asdf" instead of "nut" in search function (i.e. value which is not present in searching array) , it returns "type mismatch" error instead of "not found"